# Having fun the the post editor

Tags: discussion

I have created some interesting uses using the link syntax of `[text](url)`. These are for fun, and should not be used in quality posts.

**Comments:**

*Edit to see...*

**Whitespace:**

**Lines:**

> 

Comment: Can you give an example? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @nhinkle Click the *edit* link. He uses unreferenced footnote-style image/URL definitions.

Comment: I don't really see why this should be discussed though. One can simply put in HTML-comment tags as well. Voting to close, don't really see the point in this.

Comment: @DanielBeck Heck. You can even reference them, but they do not show.

Comment: @RedhattedCatsaysBestWishes I'm just having fun. I understand this is not a valid topic.

Comment: @iglzvx I understand! I genuinely think it's funny to do, but an active question about it doesn't serve any purpose I think! Nothing personal! (:

Comment: @RedhattedCatsaysBestWishes I know. :)

Comment: I think this should be `status-bydesign`ed ;) — nice find though!

Comment: @RedhattedCatsaysBestWishes Interesting about HTML comments is, they don't become part of the output either. I didn't know that.

Comment: @DanielBeck The system inserts HTML comments for future editors if a question is edited by the system (E.g. applied filters, etc.)

Comment: @RedhattedCatsaysBestWishes Interesting. Could you provide an example for that?

Comment: @DanielBeck I'm already looking for one! I can't remember any but I know for sure I saw them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a great way to leave messages to people that might try to edit your post.